# React proptype array with shape

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-proptypes

Is there a built-in way to use proptypes to ensure that an array of objects being passed to a component is actually an array of objects of a specific shape?

Maybe something like this?

```js
annotationRanges: PropTypes.array(PropTypes.shape({
    start: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    end: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
})),
```

Am I missing something super obvious here? Seems like this would be highly sought after.

Answer (score 482):

You can use `React.PropTypes.shape()` as an argument to `React.PropTypes.arrayOf()`:

```js
// an array of a particular shape.
ReactComponent.propTypes = {
   arrayWithShape: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.shape({
     color: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
     fontSize: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
   })).isRequired,
}
```

See the [Prop Validation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) section of the documentation.

**UPDATE**

As of `react v15.5`, using `React.PropTypes` is deprecated and the standalone package `prop-types` should be used instead :

```js
// an array of a particular shape.
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'; // ES6 

//...

var PropTypes = require('prop-types'); // ES5 with npm
ReactComponent.propTypes = {
   arrayWithShape: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
     color: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
     fontSize: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
   })).isRequired,
}
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out the use of `.isRequired` on each property of `React.PropTypes.shape`. I arrived here because I wrongly assumed that by using `.isRequired` on `React.PropTypes.arrayOf`, I didn't need it inside. To achieve full coverage validation, I actually ended up applying it directly to `React.PropTypes.shape` as well.

Comment: Yes, I was doing the exact same thing than you, but it's way more powerful to have the possibility to only flag as required the keys you want to. Explicit is always better than implicit for me by the way.

Comment: This example doesn't fail validation correctly for me. If the if `arrayWithShape` is [] (an empty array) It doesn't fail. if `arrayWithShape` is {} (an object) it does fail. If  `arrayWithShape`  is `[{dumb: 'something'}]` (an array without the correct props) it fails. I need it to fail validation if `arrayWithShape` is an empty array. I only want it to pass if it is a non empty array with objects that have props `color` and `fontsize`. What am I missing?

Comment: Worth noting you can also import these as named imports. i.e `import { shape } from 'prop-types';`

Answer (score 59):

Yes, you need to use `PropTypes.arrayOf` instead of `PropTypes.array` in the code, you can do something like this:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  annotationRanges: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      start: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      end: PropTypes.number.isRequired
    }).isRequired
  ).isRequired
}
```

Also for more details about **proptypes**, visit **Typechecking With PropTypes** [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

Comment: What's the reason for adding .isRequired to the PropTypes.shape object?

Comment: @makovkastar Because without it, `[undefined]` would pass validation

Answer (score 33):

And there it is... right under my nose:

From the react docs themselves: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html

```
// An array of a certain type
    optionalArrayOf: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.number),
```

Answer (score 9):

There's a ES6 shorthand import, you can reference. More readable and easy to type.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { arrayOf, shape, number } from 'prop-types';

class ExampleComponent extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    annotationRanges: arrayOf(shape({
      start: number,
      end: number,
    })).isRequired,
  }

  static defaultProps = {
     annotationRanges: [],
  }
}
```

Comment: Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. You should update your answer to explain what this does and how it improves on the upvoted answers this question already has.

Answer (score 1):

If I am to define the same proptypes for a particular shape multiple times, I like abstract it out to a proptypes file so that if the shape of the object changes, I only have to change the code in one place. It helps dry up the codebase a bit.

Example:

```
// Inside my proptypes.js file
import PT from 'prop-types';

export const product = {
  id: PT.number.isRequired,
  title: PT.string.isRequired,
  sku: PT.string.isRequired,
  description: PT.string.isRequired,
};


// Inside my component file
import PT from 'prop-types';
import { product } from './proptypes;


List.propTypes = {
  productList: PT.arrayOf(product)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was my solution to protect against an empty array as well:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { arrayOf, shape, string, number } from 'prop-types';

ReactComponent.propTypes = {
  arrayWithShape: (props, propName, componentName) => {
    const arrayWithShape = props[propName]
    PropTypes.checkPropTypes({ arrayWithShape:
        arrayOf(
          shape({
            color: string.isRequired,
            fontSize: number.isRequired,
          }).isRequired
      ).isRequired
    }, {arrayWithShape}, 'prop', componentName);
    if(arrayWithShape.length < 1){
      return new Error(`${propName} is empty`)
    }
  }
}
```