# Ensuring each element of an array property conforms to custom shape in React

Tags: properties, reactjs

I want to ensure every element of an array property conforms to a particular shape.

**This is different than the question answered in [React proptype array with shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32325912/react-proptype-array-with-shape).  They tested if every element matched a given pre-defined React proptype validator, in that case React.propTypes.number.**  I'm interested testing against a custom object shape.

For example:

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  static propTypes = {
    data: React.PropTypes.arrayOf({
      name: React.PropTypes.string,
      year: React.PropTypes.number,
    })
  }
}
```

This triggers a warning: `Failed propType: typeChecker is not a function Check the render method`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're close, but you need to specify what kind of proptype the array is of, and `React.PropTypes.shape` let's you specify an object with keys and their types.

```
static propTypes = {
  data: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(
    React.PropTypes.shape({
      name: React.PropTypes.string,
      year: React.PropTypes.number,
    })
  )
}
```

tip: do `import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'` so you can just use `PropTypes.`