# PropTypes validation array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-proptypes

I have an array object being passed as props the array looks something like:

```
[
  {
    "title": "eat food"
  },
  {
    "title": "Drinks",
    "sub_items": [
      {
        "title": "Beer",
        "isDrinking": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "eat Pizza"
  },
  {
    "title": "Other Drinks",
    "sub_items": [
      {
        "title": "Soda",
        "isDrinking": false
      },
      {
        "title": "Soda",
        "isDrinking": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What i want to do is add the propTypes validation, something like

title : PropTypes.string.isRequired

sub_items : PropTypes.array

sub_items : props validation inside the array such as title sting and isDrinking boolean.

note sure on how to achieve this on an array. (ps. my reactjs knowledge is very limited so excuse me if I am asking an obvious stupid question)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React proptype array with shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32325912/react-proptype-array-with-shape)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write:

```
PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  sub_items: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    isDrinking: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
  })
})).isRequired
```

Notice how `sub_items` is not required, but if it is included in one of the objects, it has to be an array of objects with `title` and `isDrinking` defined.