# How can i check if object is following exactly a certain type format in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have to check if some items object follow a certain format as below. These items are input to a component and I want to check the validity of the input.
I already wrote some code to check for the validity of the items, but I want to know if there could be a better way to write it?
Thanks!

```
{
    main: {
        id: string,
        name: string,
    },
    drilldowns: [
        {
            id: string,
            name: string,
            elements: [
                {
                    id: string,
                    name: string,
                }
            ],
        }
    ],
 }


export const isValidItem = (item) => {
    if (!item.main || (item.main && !item.main.id))
        return false;

    if (item.drilldowns) {
        const invalidDrilldowns = item.drilldowns.filter(drilldown => {
            const invalidDrilldownElements =
                drilldown.elements &&
                drilldown.elements.filter(element => {
                    return !element.id;
                });
            return (
                !drilldown.id &&
                !drilldown.elements &&
                invalidDrilldownElements.length !== 0
            );
        });
        return invalidDrilldowns.length === 0;
    }

    return true;
};
```

Comment: Maybe you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216053/typescript-how-do-i-define-interfaces-for-nested-objects)

Comment: That would be useful when developing. I am looking for a way to check validity of item as input to a component for instance. Like <component items={items} />

Comment: May you can try out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32325912/react-proptype-array-with-shape) then.

Comment: @coffeeak Could you please include optional parameters in your format? I don't know which parameters are required and which aren't.