# How to enforce Array shape and size with Prop-Types?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-props, react-proptypes

I'm trying to create a proptype that can either be a string or an array with only 1 string and 1 object shape e.g. `[10, { message: "hello world", type: "success" }]`

Currently, I have:

```
static propTypes = {
    myProp: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.string,
        PropTypes.arrayOf(
            PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, myObjectShape])
        ),
    ]),
 }
```

This will accept a string or an array that can have any amount of strings or object shapes. Is there a way to limit the array to only 1 string and 1 object shape?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React proptype array with shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32325912/react-proptype-array-with-shape)

Comment: @tdranv Hey, no it doesn't. That answer is just checking the shape of the object whereas I need to limit my array size to 2 and only accept a string and myObjectShape.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom prop type. Something along the lines of...

```js
myProp: function(props, propName, componentName) {
    if (!props[propName] || !props[propName].length !== 2) {
      return new Error(`${propName} must be an array with length 2`);
    }

    if (typeof props[propName][0] !== 'string') {
      return new Error(`The first element in ${propName} must be a string`);
    }

    // check for the shape of the object at index 1...
}
```

More about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#react.proptypes).